# Custom Attribute Not saved in Checkout Register Form - Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, customer

I need to add two fields for Customer in customer's registration. I managed to do it and its working fine for customer registration. But it is not getting saved in case of onepage checkout (if customer is trying to register himself at the time of checkout).

Below is my Code

Code for `app\code\local\ComName\ModuleName\etc\config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ComName_ModuleName>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ComName_ModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <modulename>
        <class>ComName_ModuleName_Helper</class>
      </modulename>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <modulename>
        <class>ComName_ModuleName_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1417600661_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>ComName_ModuleName</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1417600661_setup>
      <customerattribute1417600661_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1417600661_write>
      <customerattribute1417600661_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1417600661_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

Code for `app\code\local\ComName\ModuleName\Helper\Data.php`:

```
class ComName_ModuleName_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Code for `app\code\local\ComName\ModuleName\sql\customerattribute1417600661_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute("customer", "dri_license",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Driving License",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
    ));
        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "dri_license");
$used_in_forms=array();
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

I have added fields in `billing.phtml`

Please help me if anyone have any idea on what i missing

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that you need to change your XML like this:

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <new_attribute>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </new_attribute>
        </checkout_onepage_quote>
        <customer_account>
            <new_attribute>
                <to_quote>*</to_quote>
            </new_attribute>
        </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

And also - add the field to the quote in your setup file like this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$connection = $installer->getConnection();
$quote_table_name = $installer->getTable('sales/quote');
$connection->addColumn($quote_table_name, 'new_attribute', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length' => 255,
    'nullable' => false,
    'comment' => 'New Attribute',
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

*(You can, of course use the alter table call, but I like this method better.)*

Magento is first copying the fields from your request to the quote and then it's copying them back to the customer when the customer is being created.

Also, be sure that you have your new attribute ("new_attribute" in the example above) in the **customer_form_attribute** table for the **checkout_register** form_code

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the part you are missing is the conversion from quote to customer that happens when you complete the checkout process.

This can be done with a small section of xml.

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <customer_your_attribute>
                <to_customer>your_attribute</to_customer>
            </customer_your_attribute>
        </checkout_onepage_quote>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

This you copy your attribute from the customer part of the quote to the actual customer model when the quote is converted to an order.

The magic happens in the function `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::_prepareNewCustomerQuote` here you can see the call to the function `Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset('checkout_onepage_quote', 'to_customer', $quote, $customer);`