# can´t save new field in magento(1.9) customer registration checkout form

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

I followed the instructions to add a new field in customer registration from [Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration#), works perfect!

I need help to add this field to customer registration on checkout page also.

I added this to my module xml (`ea_dni` is the name of my module):

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>ea_dni/billing.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

And I added the field in `billing.phtml`

```
            <li>
                <label for="eadni"><?php echo $this->__('DNI') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="eadni" id="eadni" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getDNI()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('DNI') ?>" class="input-text" />
                </div>
            </li>
```

So, I see the new field in checkout registration form, but this field is not saving to the database!

This is my `install-1.0.0.php`

```
<?php

$this->addAttribute('customer', 'eadni', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'DNI',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'eadni');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

Can you help me? What am I missing?

Here is my app/code/local/EA/DNI/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EA_DNI>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </EA_DNI>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <ea_dni>
                <class>EA_DNI_Helper</class>
            </ea_dni>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <ea_dni_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>EA_DNI</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </ea_dni_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <ea_dni>
                    <file>ea_dni.xml</file>
                </ea_dni>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <EA_DNI>
                    <files>
                        <default>EA_DNI.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </EA_DNI>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: probably u have not created the custom attribute properly. Check here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code in `install-1.0.0.php` with the following code

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'eadni', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'DNI',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required' => 0,
    'is_system' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,

));
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
      $setup->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'eadni');
}
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'eadni')
    ->setData('used_in_forms',     array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'))
    ->save();
}

$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/quote');
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_eadni` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

and add this code in your config.xml under `<global>` tag

```
<fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
             <eadni><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></eadni>
        </customer_account>

        <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <customer_eadni>
                <to_customer>eadni</to_customer>
            </customer_eadni>
        </checkout_onepage_quote>
        <customer_account>
            <eadni>
                <to_quote>customer_eadni</to_quote>
            </eadni>
        </customer_account> 
    </fieldsets>
```

Comment: Piyush thanks, i replace install, clear chache but still not saving in database! :o(!

Comment: can you put the code of your config.xml?

Comment: I added my config.xml

Comment: i updated my answer please check .

Comment: @elismoran, Is this answer worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a similar issue. You can see my suggested solution here: [Custom Attribute Not saved in Checkout Register Form - Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46223/custom-attribute-not-saved-in-checkout-register-form-magento/71698#71698)