# Custom field don't work in checkout registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, billing-address, billing

I've created a custom module to add 10 custom fields in customer register page, following this topic, and it works fine: [Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration/65760#65760)

Perhaps, this **doesn't work in checkout registration page.** I tried many settings, but the information doesn't even get saved in sales_flat_quote table. Here's my code for reference. Thanks for your help!

sql->install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php



$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

/* --------------------------------
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
CAMPOS PARA INFORMAÇÕES DO CLIENTE
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
-------------------------------- */

/* PESSOA FÍSICA OU JURÍDICA */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'tipo', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Tipo de conta',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 35,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'tipo');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();



/* PESSOA FÍSICA - CPF */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'cpf', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'CPF',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1020,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'cpf');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();

/* PESSOA FÍSICA - NASCIMENTO */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'nascimento', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Data de nascimento',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1021,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'nascimento');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();



/* PESSOA JURÍDICA - CNPJ */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'cnpj', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'CNPJ',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1020,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'cnpj');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();


/* PESSOA JURÍDICA - RAZÃO SOCIAL */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'razao', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Razão Social',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1020,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'razao');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();


/* PESSOA JURÍDICA - NOME FANTASIA */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'fantasia', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Nome Fantasia',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1020,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'fantasia');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();



/* PESSOA JURÍDICA - INSCRIÇÃO ESTADUAL */
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'ie', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Inscrição Estadual',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1020,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'ie');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();

/* --------------------------------
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
-------------------------------- */







/* --------------------------------
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
CAMPOS PARA INFORMAÇÕES DE ENDEREÇO
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
-------------------------------- */



/* CRIA CAMPO - NÚMERO */
$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'numero', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Número',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1022,
    'required'  => true,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'numero');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer_address',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
    'customer_address_edit',
    'customer_register_address'
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();


/* CRIA CAMPO - BAIRRO*/
$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'bairro', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Bairro',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1040,
    'required'  => true,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'bairro');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer_address',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
    'customer_address_edit',
    'customer_register_address'
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();


/* CRIA CAMPO - COMPLEMENTO DO ENDEREÇO */
$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'complemento', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Complemento',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 3,
    'position'  => 1050,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'complemento');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer_address',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
    'customer_address_edit',
    'customer_register_address'
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();


/* --------------------------------
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
-------------------------------- */





$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/quote');
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_tipo` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_cpf` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_nascimento` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_cnpj` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_razao` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_fantasia` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_ie` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_numero` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_bairro` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");
$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_complemento` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ");



$installer->endSetup();
```

stackexchange_customer.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <layout>
        <customer_account_edit>
            <reference name="customer_edit">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </customer_account_edit>
        <customer_account_create>
            <reference name="customer_form_register">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>stackexchange_customer/register.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </customer_account_create>
        <checkout_onepage_index>
            <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>stackexchange_customer/form/billing.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
                <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_index>
    </layout>


config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <fieldsets>
    <checkout_onepage_quote>
         <customer_tipo>
            <to_customer>tipo</to_customer>
          </customer_tipo>
          <customer_cpf>
            <to_customer>cpf</to_customer>
          </customer_cpf>
          <customer_nascimento>
            <to_customer>nascimento</to_customer>
          </customer_nascimento>
          <customer_cnpj>
            <to_customer>cnpj</to_customer>
          </customer_cnpj>
          <customer_razao>
            <to_customer>razao</to_customer>
          </customer_razao>
          <customer_fantasia>
            <to_customer>fantasia</to_customer>
          </customer_fantasia>
          <customer_ie>
            <to_customer>ie</to_customer>
          </customer_ie>
          <customer_numero>
            <to_customer>numero</to_customer>
          </customer_numero>
          <customer_bairro>
            <to_customer>bairro</to_customer>
          </customer_bairro>
          <customer_complemento>
            <to_customer>complemento</to_customer>
          </customer_complemento>
     </checkout_onepage_quote> 
    <checkout_onepage_billing> 
        <tipo> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </tipo>
        <cpf> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </cpf>
        <nascimento> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </nascimento>
        <cnpj> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </cnpj>
        <razao> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </razao>
        <fantasia> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </fantasia>
        <ie> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </ie>
        <numero> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </numero>
        <bairro> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </bairro>
        <complemento> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </complemento>
    </checkout_onepage_billing> 
    <customer_account>
        <tipo>
           <to_quote>customer_tipo</to_quote>
         </tipo>
         <cpf>
           <to_quote>customer_cpf</to_quote>
         </cpf>
         <nascimento>
           <to_quote>customer_nascimento</to_quote>
         </nascimento>
         <cnpj>
           <to_quote>customer_cnpj</to_quote>
         </cnpj>
         <razao>
           <to_quote>customer_razao</to_quote>
         </razao>
         <fantasia>
           <to_quote>customer_fantasia</to_quote>
         </fantasia>
         <ie>
           <to_quote>customer_ie</to_quote>
         </ie>
         <numero>
           <to_quote>customer_numero</to_quote>
         </numero>
         <bairro>
           <to_quote>customer_bairro</to_quote>
         </bairro>
         <complemento>
           <to_quote>customer_complemento</to_quote>
         </complemento>
     </customer_account>   
    <sales_convert_order>
        <customer_tipo>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_tipo>
        <customer_cpf>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_cpf>
        <customer_nascimento>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_nascimento>
        <customer_cnpj>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_cnpj>
        <customer_razao>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_razao>
        <customer_fantasia>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_fantasia>
        <customer_ie>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_ie>
        <customer_numero>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_numero>
        <customer_bairro>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_bairro>
        <customer_complemento>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_complemento>
    </sales_convert_order> 
    </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <stackexchange_customer>
                <class>StackExchange_Customer_Helper</class>
            </stackexchange_customer>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <stackexchange_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>StackExchange_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </stackexchange_customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stackexchange_customer>
                    <file>stackexchange_customer.xml</file>
                </stackexchange_customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And, under billing.phtml, here's the code for a row with two attributes, for reference:

```
<li class="fields pessoa-fisica">
                    <!-- || CPF || -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:cpf"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('CPF') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[cpf]" id="billing:cpf" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCpf()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('CPF')) ?>" class="input-text cpf" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ||  || -->
                    <!-- || DATA DE NASCIMENTO || -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:nascimento" ><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Data de Nascimento') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[nascimento]" id="billing:nascimento" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getNascimento()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Data de Nascimento')) ?>" class="input-text nascimento" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ||  || -->
                </li>
```

PS: As you can see, 3 of the 10 customer attributes are from "customer_address". I don't know if it changes something, but i hope it does.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone facing the same issue: Check if you aren't trying to include **customer** and **customer_address** fields at the same time. That's my case, i've done the process only with the field for 'customer' tab and it worked like a charm.

For everyone wondering, here's the reference to add, on checkout page:

On customer tab: [Custom Attribute Not saved in Checkout Register Form - Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46223/custom-attribute-not-saved-in-checkout-register-form-magento)

On address tab: https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/ (Notice the XMl, on "to_order_address" and other addresses like this.